# In peoplesoft pagelet wizard, does XML need to declare the type of XML for the XSL to work?

Tags: xml, xslt, peoplesoft, xml-declaration

I have an RSS feed that I want in a pagelet.

http://studentaffairs.csun.edu/calendar/admin/Feed.php?CALID=39&TYPE=RSS&tags=Men%27s%20Basketball

The XML of this feed does not have an XML declaration. The transformation worked fine when I used visual studios to see it locally but in PeopleSoft it gives me an error.

Is the error because the XML declaration is missing?

Is there a work around for this?

I do not have access to change the layout of the RSS feed.

**PeopleSoft error:**

> An error has occurred while trying to perform the XSL transformation.

This is because either:

1. The DataSource did not return valid XML or
2. The XSL for transformation is invalid.

**UPDATE:** I confirmed that the problem was the missing XML declaration. But is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Don't know much about peoplesoft, but maybe this link is interesting? http://bloggingaboutoracleapplications.org/peoplesoft-and-rss-feeds/

Comment: Thank you but I already saw this. But in case anyone else looks at this. In step 5 in the picture you can see that the first line in the xml is <?xml version ......?> That is whats missing from the rss feed that I THINK is breaking it in peoplesoft.

Comment: What you could do is pick an example of an RSS feed that can be handled, and then remove the first line (`<?xml ...`). If it breaks on the stripped version then you are sure that that is the cause.

Comment: What is the XSL you are applying?

Comment: I wanted to do that to test it but in peoplesoft it will not let me edit the XML (or I just haven't figured it out)

This is not the final XSL but I tried a minimal XSL to test it and got the same error:


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  Hello World!
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Just can upload your own RSS XML file somewhere and test with that.

Comment: Okay I did that. It is because that XML version is missing. Is there a work around to avoid this in peoplesoft?

Comment: Don't know much about peoplesoft. Please update your question with the knowledge you have just acquired. Maybe someone else can answer it.

Comment: How are you handling the XML? A DOM object or something?

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post for one possible answer

http://i-like-trains.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/peoplesoft-in-windows-2008.html

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there needed to be a "tmp" directory created under the "pshome"/appserv/"appserv"/logs/tmp ... Once i created this tmp folder the pagelet wizard could then dynamically render the XSLT and it began working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case you manage to have the XML loaded as a DOM object, you could probably add the declaration yourself. This will make the XML valid and everything else would work fine.